# adding systemctl command to yocto image

Tags: yocto, systemd, bitbake, openembedded, systemctl

I have a building image that doesn't have a "system" or "systemctl" command available.
I've found the recipe in poky/recipes-core/systemd and am unsure how to add it to my final image, and I am having a lot of trouble deciphering the manual.

I've tried adding a line to my IMAGE_INSTALL variable in my image recipe as well as adding DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL = " systemd"
to my local.conf file.

Is my base understanding incorrect that this is enough to add it to a completed image?

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to add the following lines to `local.conf` (or distro configuration, if you are building a custom one) to enable systemd on your images:

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscript = "systemd-compat-units"
```

Comment: With recent versions you will also need 'DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"' and 'DISTRO_FEATURES:append = "systemd usrmerge"'